# Select and call_user_func_array issue

Tags: php, mysqli

I've this function:

```
private function db_bind_array($stmt, &$row) {
  $md = $stmt->result_metadata();
  $param = array();
  while($field = $md->fetch_field()) { $param[] = &$row[$field->name];}
  return call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_result'), $param);
}
private function db_query($sql, $bind_param, $param) {
  if($stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql)) {
  if(!$bindRet = call_user_func_array(array($stmt,'bind_param'),
  array_merge(array($bind_param), $param))) $this->Terminate();
  if(!$stmt->execute()) $this->Terminate();
  $res = array();
  if($this->db_bind_array($stmt, $res)) return array($stmt, $res);
  }
}

protected function Select($recs, $table, $where, $bind_param, $param, $order_by = '', $sort = '', $limit = 1) {
  if($order_by != '') $order_by = 'ORDER BY '.$order_by;
  $sql = "SELECT $recs FROM $table WHERE $where $order_by $sort LIMIT $limit";
  return $this->ExeSelect($sql, $bind_param, $param);
}
private function ExeSelect($sql, $bind_param, $param) {
  if($res = $this->db_query($sql, $bind_param, array(&$param))) {
  $stmt = $res[0]; $row  = $res[1];
  while($stmt->fetch()) {$this->row = $row; return $row;}
  $stmt->close();
  }
}
```

And I use it:
    $row = $this->Select('id, name, title, 'Articles', where id >, 'i', 10, 'DESC', '', 10)

The problem is that it returns only one record instead of 10.
What's the problem?
Thanks

Comment: oh pleeeease, for all the goodness sake, don't make use a function like this. Just look at the way you are calling it! It's just impossible to tell what you are selecting! It's totally uncomprehencible!

Comment: Just use your ExeSelect() - it's the only sensible function to use

Comment: eh, that's what I've found.....
Have you something better?

Comment: Just call ExeSelect() all the way. it is more flexible, readable and safe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line: `while($stmt->fetch()) {$this->row = $row; return $row;}`. You immediately return that result. Build an array before you return it.

```
private function ExeSelect($sql, $bind_param, $param) {
    $ret = array();
    if($res = $this->db_query($sql, $bind_param, array(&$param))) {
        $stmt = $res[0]; $row  = $res[1];
        while($stmt->fetch()) {$ret[] = $row; }
        $stmt->close();
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

Comment: fetch_assoc for loop in it?

Comment: To be honest, you should throw away most of the code and just use the mysqli functions. You are not creating any meaningful object abstraction but rather adding more confusion.

Comment: For example here http://www.pontikis.net/blog/dynamically-bind_param-array-mysqli

Comment: It has "get_result()" function....I had this one before my host server tell me to change it cause it excludes "mysqlnd" extension.
And so I found that function...
I'm in trouble..

Comment: No suggestions? Please

Comment: What do you need? `$rows = $this->Select('id, name, title, 'Articles', where id >, 'i', 10, 'DESC', '', 10); foreach ($rows as $row) print_r($row);`

Comment: If you can....
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22881403/implelemtation-of-call-user-func-array-without-mysqlnd-mysql-native-driver